# What unsafe javascript should I block?

Tags: php, javascript, xss

I am writing a PHP script that takes javascript code and writes it out in someones browser, works great, but I want the javascript to be able to be written by anyone, so I need to validate that certain things are not added to the javascript code like redirects and alert boxes.

What I'm asking is simply for suggestions for things to be censored out of the javascript, I have a fairly extensive list right now but I just want to make sure there is not anything obvious, or extremely obscure I have missed.

Comment: "What unsafe javascript should I block?" All of it. You can never be 100% safe from these things.

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530811/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all honesty, working with PHP and JavaScript can be a bit of hell. Preventing dangerous JavaScript isn't 100% foolproof, as some can just load their own JavaScript code from a different domain and just do what they please.

However, you mention that you have a "honeypot" of sorts?

Comment: Yes, but I did more research, and the functions and snippets that they block can be totally circumvented. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530811/how-to-allow-users-to-write-javascript-with-security

Comment: Very interesting! This is something I'd like to test out myself. Thanks for your research.